# How to join 2 lists in redis

Tags: list, redis

**Intro**

I'm trying to do something that sounds simple, but so far I'm not having luck finding the answer. I have 2 lists in a redis 2.6.4 standalone server(no cluster):

```
list1 = [4, 5 ,6]

list2 = [1, 2, 3]
```

**The problem**

And I need to concatenate the lists to produce something like this:

```
list3 = list1 + list2

list3 = [4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3] <- I need to preserve order, list1 and then list 2

list4 = list2 + list1

list4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

**The question**

Since redis use linked lists to store this lists I was expecting to have a straightforward way of doing this, does such a way exists? what's the usual way of doing this in redis?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this safely is to use LUA scripting, this way you have the guarantee that the resulting list is not missing any element (and you can easily preserve the order).

If LUA is not an option then you need to do this client side and use watch those keys for changes (see transaction in redis and WATCH command)

Comment: I understand, but even using LUA the only option is to loop trough all the items in one of the lists and copy it to the other list? LUA is def an option here

Comment: yes, in the end its going to be a O(N) operation, how big are the list you need to concatenate ?

Comment: I have a few lists with a combined size of 16-18 million items, the rest have a combined size of 1-3 million items. Each list contains only ids, not entire objects but the problem is almost the same, I'm failing to find an O(1) operation to join the lists. With combined size I mean the sum of the size of the two lists I'm trying to join.

Comment: Well then you have a problem. an alternative option is not to copy the data but just keep track of concats (eg. _list1 = [1,2,3]; list1 = ['_list1',]; when you want to concat list1 and list2 in list3 you create list3 as ['_list1', '_list2']) your client needs to be smart enough to handle this indirection and also be able to walk trough different lists

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Redis command using Lua:

```
eval "for i,l in ipairs(ARGV) do for i,v in ipairs(redis.call('lrange',l,0,-1)) do redis.call('rpush',KEYS[1],v) end end" 1 list3 list1 list2
```

- As an added bonus you can specify any number of lists to append into your master list by simply adding more list keys at the end